# Configuring moveit_servo for use with tmr_ros1 (techman robot)

Tags: ros, moveit, rosservice, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone. I have a problem and I hope you can help me.

I'm using ROS Noetic and [the tmr_ros1](https://github.com/TechmanRobotInc/tmr_ros1) pkg.
Right now I am trying to use the realtime servoing functionnality for Moveit, [see this](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/realtime_servo/realtime_servo_tutorial.html#getting-started).

`tmr_ros1` is only using the `FollowJointTrajectory` controller and the tutorial says that i need to switch my controller. But the controller_manager is not runing so i can't call:

```
rosservice call /controller_manager/switch_controller "start_controllers: ['joint_group_position_controller']...
```

However as I am not using a gazebo simulation I can't just add this to my urdf:

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
    <robotNamespace>/MYROBOT</robotNamespace>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

So I tried serveral things like starting the controller in a launch file but nothing worked. And I kinda messed my workspace (no big deal ;)

Can anyone point me toward a direction to use the controller manager with a real robot instead of using Moveit's basic manager `Trajectory execution is managing controllers` All of this aim to change my controller to `joint_group_position_controller`.

Have a nice day !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396193/configuring-moveit_servo-for-use-with-tmr_ros1-(techman-robot)/) by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2022-02-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-02-15**:
I've changed the title of your question as there are plenty of "real robots" with drivers which *are* `ros_control` based and for which using `moveit_servo` would be a matter of following the tutorial you mention.

The real question here appears to be how would you go about configuring everything such that it works with a *Techman robot*, or specifically: with a Techman robot *using their `tmr_ros1` driver packages*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can anyone point me toward a direction to use the controller manager with a real robot instead of using Moveit's basic manager `Trajectory execution is managing controllers` All of this aim to change my controller to `joint_group_position_controller`.

You can't use any `ros_control` based solution as `tmr_ros1` is not `ros_control` based.

It uses a regular stand-alone node which exposes the `FollowJointTrajectoryAction` server.

You'll have to investigate whether there is any possibility of sending position or velocity commands to `tm_driver` in any other way. Without being able to stream position or velocity setpoints, I'm not sure you can use `moveit_servo` in a meaningful way.

And note: "stream[ing] position or velocity setpoints" implies a low-latency connection. Servoing only really works well if that's something you have to your target robot.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on 2022-02-15**:
Thank you very much for your time !
It seems like I need to investigate furthermore this `tmr_ros1` driver.

**Comment by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on 2022-02-15**:
The driver has a demo program that can send positions to the robot called `demo_set_positions.cpp`
Do you think that if I run it fast and pass the outgoing positions from `moveit_servo` it might work ?
Because I can't find another way.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-02-15**:
I assume you are referring to [TechmanRobotInc/tmr_ros1/demo/src/demo_set_positions.cpp](https://github.com/TechmanRobotInc/tmr_ros1/blob/4bf1e0d71e0a62be40204fd3d026339faa7dffe9/demo/src/demo_set_positions.cpp)?

If that's the case: that seems to use ROS services which use a service exposed by the driver, which then executes [this code](https://github.com/TechmanRobotInc/tmr_ros1/blob/8d0a781255fbbd51aa9379ca8536ee2dc102bc7b/tm_driver/src/tm_ros_service.cpp#L158-L174) which finally seems to use some sort of text-based scripting interface to the TM controller.

I don't have any direct experience with TM robots nor controllers, but ROS services incur quite some latency. They're not used very often for anything "real-time".

You could *try*, but you'd have to create something which accepts position setpoints over a topic (which is what `moveit_servo` uses) and then uses a service client to communicate with the TM driver.

Absolutely no guarantees this will work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-02-15**:
I would advise you to ask the TM developers for more information about the available interfaces.

At this point I believe your initial question is answered: there doesn't appear to be a way for you to use `moveit_servo`with this driver -- or at least not without custom development, and even then, it's questionable the performance will be sufficient / satisfactory.

**Comment by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on 2022-02-15**:
A big thanks to you sir !

**Comment by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on 2022-02-16**:
I found this in `moveit_servo` config file and will try it:

```
# What type of topic does your robot driver expect?
# Currently supported are std_msgs/Float64MultiArray (for ros_control JointGroupVelocityController or JointGroupPositionController)
# or trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory (for Universal Robots and other non-ros_control robots)
command_out_type: std_msgs/Float64MultiArray
```

Because this looks interesting: or `trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory (for Universal Robots and other non-ros_control robots`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-02-16**:
It's a really old comment (as "Universal Robots" don't need that at all any more), but sure. Try and see whether it works sufficiently.

(I doubt it, but perhaps for your use-case it's enough)